# List all blogs, but exclude the main site

Tags: php, functions, multisite, shortcode

I am using this `function` that gives me a `shortcode` I can paste anywhere on the site. It lists all blogs in the `multisite network` a user has, but I would like to hide the main site from the list.
Can someone help to adjust the snippet?

-Extra question. - is it possible to show blogs website preview like Facebook?

```
function show_blog_list() {
 
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ($user_id == 0) {
        echo 'You are not logged in.';
    } else {
        echo '<h2>Here is your blog list</h2>';
        $user_blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $user_id );
        foreach ($user_blogs AS $user_blog) {
            echo '<li><a href="'.$user_blog->siteurl.'">'.$user_blog->blogname.'</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
 
}
add_shortcode( 'bloglist', 'show_blog_list' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it, but it looks like [`get_main_site_id`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_main_site_id/) is what you want to figure that out, so therefore your code might look like:

```
$mainSiteId = get_main_site_id();
foreach ($user_blogs AS $user_blog) {
    if ($userblog->site_id != $mainSiteId) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.$user_blog->siteurl.'">'.$user_blog->blogname.'</a></li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am totally new to php. Is this something I add to my existing code above? What I am looking for is to hide the main blog from the list.

Comment: This is a modification to the similar looking part in your existing code. You just need to add/change the bits that I added

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how it can be adjusted to hide the main site?

Comment: @Sanfe That's what the code in my answer does. Did you try it? You may want to read the answer above as the code should be understandable.